# I can't install doctrine/dbal dependency on composer laravel

Tags: php, doctrine, composer-php, laravel-5.1

I am searching for help, but I don't finded

I can't install doctrine/dbal dependency on composer. 
I already tried by

> composer require doctrine/dbal

And appeared
 "[Composer\Downloader\TransportException]
  The "http://packagist.org/p/doctrine/dbal%24ae0751c3a3a978245544ffce33fda7e3fe9d8ea418e30b2adac790a49a65f10b.json" file could not be downloaded (HTTP/1.1 302 Found)"

really, when i acess the adress the page shows:

"Oh noes, 404!
It looks like you requested a page that was not found.
Go back to the homepage or use the search above to find the package you want."

I tried by composer.json file  writing

> "doctrine/dbal": "v2.4.2"

and then (in command line)

> composer update

The same error occurs.

My laravel: laravel/framework": "5.1.*"

Can somebody help me?
thanks